# what is the use of esc_attr() function?

Tags: functions

I want to know use of **esc_attr()**?
how it is used?
Any example would be highly help!

```
esc_attr( $variable )
```

Comment: [Have you read the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/)?

Comment: Yes, i read it..
i didn't get it
Please help me clear it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

esc_attr() is written specifically for escaping a string that is to be used as an html attribute, which means also escaping single and double-quote characters etc.

In general, it's better to use the data validation API that WP provides rather than the generic PHP functions.

Comment: sure, it works now! thanks for the concept clearance!

Answer (score 1):

esc_attr() is writing for escaping a string that is to be used as an html attribute.
When escaping the values of attributes that accept URIs (like href and src), it is important to pass the value through esc_url().

Note: that when using esc_url(), you don’t need to also use esc_attr().